# threefolds with $h^{2, 0}=1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The question is almost contained in the title.

I am looking for interesting examples of smooth, projective threefolds $X$ (preferably over a number field) such that 
$
H^0(X, \Omega^2_X)
$ or equivalently $H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ has dimension one. Who can provide such examples?

Comment: By "interesting" do you mean threefolds which are not $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ bundles over a surface with $h^{2,0}=1$?

Comment: Not necessarily

Answer (score 4):

You can prove that such threefolds are either P^1-fibration over a base,
which is a surface with $h^{2,0}=1$, or have pseudoeffective canonical
bundle: arXiv:1304.7891, Corollary 4.3. In the later case you can run the
minimal model program, obtaining that your variety is either general type or 
is a (singular) fibration  with Calabi-Yau fibers over a general type 
variety with canonical  singularities. However, since $h^{2,0}=1$, your 
base has $h^{2,0}<2$,  and this restriction is pretty strong: either 
you have an elliptic fibration over a surface, or a K3 or toric 
fibration over an elliptic curve.

Comment: One comment: a $\mathbb{P}^1$-fibration in this context may only be etale locally trivial (away from the discriminant locus).  There are "conic bundles" that are not Zariski locally trivial over surfaces with $h^{2,0} =1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be a K3 surface, and let $S^{[2]}$ be the Hilbert scheme parametrizing length-2 subschemes of $S.$  Then $S^{[2]}$ is a smooth projective 4-fold with $h^{2,0}=1.$  If $D \subset S^{[2]}$ is a smooth ample divisor on $S^{[2]},$ then Kodaira vanishing implies that $D$ is a smooth projective threefold with $h^{2,0}=1.$